# NUnit equivalent of RSpec's expect change

Tags: nunit

RSpec has a nifty expect/change construct, that goes like this:

```
expect{sut.SomeMethod}.to change{repo.count}.by(1)
```

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/expect-change

Does NUnit have anything like this as well? Something along the line of:

```
Expect(() => sut.SomeMethod()).Changes<int>(() => repo.Count()).By(1);
```

Right now, I implement this test like this:

```
int prevCount = repo.Count();
sut.SomeMethod();
int newCount = repo.Count();
Assert.That(newCount, Is.EqualTo(prevCount + 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Essentially, test of side effects always require multiple statements. If `SomeMethod` were a function returning the count, then you could test it in a single statement.